# Finding only one world from pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, n-gram, python-re

I have a data frame that contains n-gram strings in the column. I want to find the rows which contain only one targeted word only. How can I do that? 
I have tried this code:
`df[df["column_name].str.match("targeted_word")]`. But this gives all values after or before that target word. I need to get the rows with only the target word.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For full match, `df[df["column_name].eq("targeted_word")]`

Comment: Thanks thats it thats the solution :)